# Confusion About Inversion of z-Transform

Tags: complex-analysis, z-transform

I got two method to take inversion of $X(z)$

### 1. Inversion Integral Formula

$$ X(z) = x(0) + x(T)z^{-1} + x(2T)z^{-2} + ... + x(kT)z^{-k} $$

where we try to isolate $x(kT)$ as a residue of $x(kT)z^{-1}$

$$ X(z)z^{k-1} = x(0)z^{k-1} + x(T)z^{k-2} + x(2T)z^{k-3} + ... + x(kT)z^{-1} $$

$$ x(kT) = \frac{1}{j2\pi}\oint_{C}X(z)z^{k-1}dz $$

Thus 
$$ x(kT) = \sum{Res(X(z)z^{k-1})} $$

### 2. Partial Fraction Method

I don't mention about this method let me go through my quesetion.

---

I got a $X(z)$ like this:

$$ X(z) = \frac{z(1-e^{-aT})}{(z-1)(z-e^{-aT})} $$

**Using Inversion Integral Formula:**

$$ X(z)z^{k-1} = \frac{z^{k}(1-e^{-aT})}{(z-1)(z-e^{-aT})} $$

$$ Res(X(z)z^{k-1}, 1) = 1 $$
$$ Res(X(z)z^{k-1}, e^{-aT}) = -e^{-akT} $$

Then,

$$ x(kT) = u(kT) - e^{-akT}u(kT) $$

**Using Partial Fraction Method:**

$$ X(z) = \frac{z(1-e^{-aT})}{(z-1)(z-e^{-aT})} = \frac{Res(X(z), 1)}{z-1} + \frac{Res(X(z), e^{-aT})}{z-e^{-aT}} $$

$$ X(z) = \frac{z^{-1}}{(1-z^{-1})} + \frac{-e^{-aT}z^{-1}}{1-e^{-aT}z^{-1}} $$

Then,

$$ x(kT) = u((k-1)T) - e^{-aT}(e^{-aT})^{(k-1)}u((k-1)T) $$

$$ x(kT) = u((k-1)T) - (e^{-aT})^{k}u(kT) $$

---

I expect to get same result but I got different although they are similar. My question is why?

Comment: Hi @RonGordon. I calculate different functions of residues at $e^{-aT}$. In inversion integral formula, I calculate the residue for $X(z)z^{k-1}$ but in partial fraction I calculate the residue for $X(z)$. I thnik there is no mistake here. What do you think?

Comment: yes, you are right, I apologize.